# Geometric Mean of Distance Function on disk

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is an old extra credit problem that I have yet to solve, I was hoping for some ideas:

> Let $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n \in D(0,r)$.  Define function $f(z) = [ d(z,p_1) d(z,p_2) \cdots d(z,p_n) ]^\frac{1}{n}$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Show that there exists two points $x_1, x_2 \in \partial D(0,r)$ such that $f(x_1) < r$ and $f(x_2) > r$.